# Getting the Sum of Multiple Indicators by Row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

New to the community and have limited experience with the subject. I'm trying to create a column that gets the sum of indicators row by row. So the column would total each indicator, giving me a total of 3 for the first customer, and 2 for the second. Using Microsoft Sql Server Mgmt Studio. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Customer      Date       Ind1   Ind2   Ind3    Ind4
 12345       1-1-15       1     0      1       1
 12346       1-2-15       0     1      1       0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT Customer
       , Date
       , Ind1
       , Ind2
       , Ind3
       , Ind4
       , Ind1+Ind2+Ind3+Ind4 As Indicators
  FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Replace `TABLE_NAME` with whatever name the table have. If you dont want all the `Ind1,Ind2,Ind3,Ind4` columns reported, use

```
SELECT Customer
       , Date
       , Ind1+Ind2+Ind3+Ind4 As Indicators
  FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 3):

do you mean this:

```
select customer,date, ind1+ind2+ind3 as Indicators from table_name order by Indicators
```

notice: your columns may have `null` values so use this:

```
select customer,date, isnull(ind1,0)+isnull(ind2,0)+isnull(ind3,0) as Indicators
from table_name order by Indicators
```

Answer (score 2):

Select Customer, Date, Ind1 + Ind2 + Ind3 + Ind4 As Indicators

Comment: This assumes a default value of 0 on the Ind columns, if the columns are nullable then you need to substitute isnull(ind,0)

Comment: Thanks! This solution in combination with the others worked for me.